# Replace quotes by guillemets

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i replace quotes (`""`) in text with guillemets (`«` and `»`)?
I tried the usual method (replace with regexp) for replacing, but it turned out badly - I do not know how to determine if an opening quote or a closing quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `replace` with a regex - `/"(.*?)"/g` to replace the whole "word".

```js
console.log(
  '"word1" word2 "word3"'.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '«$1»'))
```

Or

```js
console.log(
  '"word1" word2 "word3"'.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, (a, b) => `«${b}»`));
```

https://regex101.com/r/9s68XL/1